# How can I change Menu's Text color?

Tags: c#, c++, python, winapi, wxwidgets

I want to change Menu's Text color, but not MenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able  if its Visual c# you should be able to right click the widget and adjust the foreground property. Foreground usually sets the text color in Visual .net widgets like Labels, buttons, textboxes, so I think it'll probably be there for menus.

In Xaml:

```
    <Menu Foreground="Red">
        <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Didn't see the menu item but not menu... The **File** will be blue **Edit** will be red.. You datatemplate to set your style depending on the menu item

```
  <Menu Foreground="Red">
        <MenuItem Foreground="Blue" Header="_File"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows form application, in code behide of the form, in the constructor just after InitializeComponent(), set color property of the menu, like this:

```
 MyMenu.ForeColor = Color.White;
```